# Two different signatures in one envelope by using embedded signing view REST API PHP

Tags: docusignapi

We are using REST API to sign on docusign documents in our application. Its working great when I used REST API (Embedded Signing).

But we got new requirement as below.

Actually parents/childrens are joined in our application, at the time of joining we are taking parent signature on the documents as of now, new change is need to take children signature as well in the same envelope on the documents at the same time.

Is it possible with using REST API PHP? Please help on this ASAP.

Thanks,
Srinivas Reddy. A

Answer (score 0):

The answer in this post describes the process/flow for conducting embedded signing for multiple recipients:

[I need to get Document signature by Spouse and its optional. how to do it with Docusign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847728/i-need-to-get-document-signature-by-spouse-and-its-optional-how-to-do-it-with-d)